# What is the word for object that take lots of time to prepare, and then you can only use them for a very little time? (like Drones)

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for things that take lots of time to prepare (or charge) and then you are able to use them for a short time until you have to prepare (or charge) them again?

For example, Drones take 2 hours to charge batteries and you can use them for only 15 minutes.

Is there a word describing this?

Comment: The time it takes to turn a sortie around is called the **recycle time**. After it has been turned around, it is available. Its flight time is called its **endurance** Most gadgets with long turnarounds and short endurance spend a lot of time just sitting there being available. There isn't any engineering term that is the ratio of those two numbers.

Comment: Cooking food takes hours, but eating the cooked food takes minutes. :)

Comment: Something that has a poor cost benefit ratio. Inefficient? Unsatisfying? Disappointing?

Comment: Cherry blossoms, cicadas, pulled pork, fine whisky.

Comment: Old tools had a 'duty cycle.'  The 'duty cycle' described how long a tool could be used before it overheated.  Once overheated, a tool would need to cool before it could go back into use.  A 25% duty cycle meant a tool can be used for 15min, but would require 45min to cool before it could be reused.  A low "duty cycle" or perhaps a low "service cycle" may be used to describe the trait of the object.

Comment: If you get a lot out of it (albeit for a short period) once it's ready, you can say that it's *worth the wait*.

Comment: I call mine a Dyson Stick.

Comment: Maybe it’s ***high maintenance***

Comment: The prime example in my world is **food**. Takes ages to make, is gone in five minutes. :-(

Answer (score 1):

"High-maintenance", *depending on how strict you are about what constitutes a single word*, signals the amount of work you're going to have to put in.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most direct answer to Mihai is: no, there is no generally accepted single-word term for what you describe (though it would be useful).

As a native American English speaker, I find the [comment from Agriculturist](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326271/what-is-the-word-for-object-that-take-lots-of-time-to-prepare-and-then-you-can#comment748323_326271) to be the closest and best alternative. I believe "low duty cycle" would be pretty well understood by an audience that was too non-technical.

Answer (score -1):

I think a good choice of word here would be **ephemeral**, as it usually implies something valued that is fleeting, though you may also want to qualify a particular attribute that is short-lived.

e.g. "Halley's Comet is a beautiful if not ephemeral sight."

Comment: I don't think this fits the description/example

Answer (score -1):

I'd keep it simple and describe the "return on investment" as it relates to time spent in preparation compared to period of operation.